# Should the [startup] tag go away?

Tags: discussion, tagging

For me, this tag is unhelpful.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/startup

Answer (score 3):

No, for Pete's sake don't delete that, it's my favorite tag!  Think of the kittens!

Comment: I think it is a poor name but a valuable concept. Initialization seems like a better name IMO. There is a subset of things that can go wrong when the database is starting up/initializing. While I'm no expert I think it is conceivable that someone could be well versed in all the things that can go wrong when a database is initializing.

Comment: @Erik you should post this suggestion as an answer, not in comments.

Comment: gee, I thought it was for people that were working for a newly incorporated business.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should go away.  There is no reason on earth why it should exist.